# how will i create the react app but this error keeps coming

Tags: reactjs

Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\Souvik'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
at exit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:97:27)
at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:216:3)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20
at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:225:22)
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:263:24
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:81:7
at Array.forEach ()
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:80:13
at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:171:20)
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:97
var doExit = npm.config.loaded ? npm.config.get('_exit') : true
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
at exit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:97:27)
at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:216:3)
at process.emit (events.js:210:5)
at process._fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:150:25)
Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 7

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: npm i -g create-react-app

Step 2: If it is already installed, update it

Step 3: create-react-app

Try the above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write this in your terminal (please only write this in your application folder!): `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

Comment: another SSL error is coming .... can you please check it ? i've posted that in another thread in my profile\

Comment: downgrade to node 16.